# LIMIT 1 not respected when used with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Postgres 14

Tags: postgresql

I have a queue implementation with Postgres where I fetch messages from the queue table by updating one row and then return it and later delete it.

My query looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE queue_messages
SET status = 'leased'
WHERE id = ANY(
    SELECT id FROM queue_messages
    WHERE status = 'pending'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING *
```

On most cases this works fine, and I get a single row back and a single row is updated with status `leased`. But, in some cases when a concurrent write is happening to the table I get multiple rows back, typically all pending rows from the table. They are also updated to have status `leased`.

I've tried adding a lock with `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(id)` in combination with `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` but it doesn't seem to help. If I remove `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` I no longer get multiple rows back, but then it's not safe for concurrent leasing of messages.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WITH-query (Common Table Expression / CTE) should work, by doing something like this

```sql
WITH _queue_ids AS (
    SELECT id FROM queue_messages
    WHERE status = 'pending'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
) UPDATE queue_messages
SET status = 'leased'
WHERE id = ANY(SELECT id FROM _queue_ids)
RETURNING *
```

Your problem seems to appear when the query-planner creates a plan with a nested loop over the limit-subquery, from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497 :

> The planner may choose to generate a plan that executes a nested loop over the LIMITing subquery, causing more UPDATEs than LIMIT, e.g.:

> `Update on buganalysis [...] rows=5`

```
   ->  Nested Loop
         ->  Seq Scan on buganalysis
         ->  Subquery Scan on sub [...] loops=11
               ->  Limit [...] rows=2
                     ->  LockRows
                           ->  Sort
                                 ->  Seq Scan on buganalysis
```

> The way to fix the above was to wrap the LIMIT subquery in its own CTE, as the CTE is materialized it will not return different results on different iterations of the nested loop.

Comment: You should add some explanation why.

Comment: To be honest, I am not a 100% sure why, I just knew this way of going about the problem works from experience. I would assume it is related to the subquery being evaluated multiple times in OP's query, while in my solution we ensure that the query is run once and that the result is "immutable" when evaluating the update-query.

Comment: Great! That is helpful information, and you should add it to the answer. You could try `EXPLAIN` and see if that supports your theory.